# WolframScript fails silently intermittently (but only when connected to internet)

Tags: scripting

When I execute "wolframscript" from a bash shell repeatedly, it sometimes starts up, and sometimes fails.  Failures occur about half of the time. The failure is silent.

If I turn wifi off (so that I am not connected to the internet), it always works, though it prints a warning that my license will expire soon.

This is surely a bug, at least in terms of poor error reporting. I have not been able to find any mention of anyone else having this problem, and I can't seem to find any system error log that would give insight.

I have a Home Edition license.

Thanks for any advice.

```
Robs-MBP-111:math-tablet robertread$ wolframscript
Wolfram Language 12.0.0 Engine for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.
Robs-MBP-111:math-tablet robertread$ wolframscript
Wolfram Language 12.0.0 Engine for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:=                                                                         
Robs-MBP-111:math-tablet robertread$ wolframscript
Wolfram Language 12.0.0 Engine for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:=                                                                         
Robs-MBP-111:math-tablet robertread$ wolframscript
Wolfram Language 12.0.0 Engine for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:=                                                                         
Robs-MBP-111:math-tablet robertread$ wolframscript
Wolfram Language 12.0.0 Engine for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:=                                                                         
Robs-MBP-111:math-tablet robertread$ wolframscript
Wolfram Language 12.0.0 Engine for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:=                                                                         
Robs-MBP-111:math-tablet robertread$ wolframscript
Wolfram Language 12.0.0 Engine for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.
Robs-MBP-111:math-tablet robertread$ wolframscript
Wolfram Language 12.0.0 Engine for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.
Robs-MBP-111:math-tablet robertread$ logout
```